# Java AffineTransform different output on Windows

Tags: java, windows, graphics, affinetransform

I am trying to print some text vertically from a java applet. This is my code that makes the transform:

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

at.setRotate(Math.toRadians(270), xPos, yPos);
g2d.setTransform(at);
g2d.drawString(this.toBePrinted[i].title, xPos, yPos);
```

On my OSX system the lines get printed at correct size vertically displayed. On Windows the same code produces different output, the size of the text and the distances between text are very small.

If I remove the **setRotate** line, the text on windows gets printed horizontally at correct size. Somehow that line adds another transform in size only for windows computers? 
Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?